# Android implement a Filterable adapter efficiently

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-filterable

I want to add a filter on my `ListView`.

I already know how to do it (by making the adapter implement `Filterable`), but I got some questions about it.

1) The examples I've seen always iterate through the entire list of items, checking for each one if it needs to filter and are returning the items. Then getView instantiate only the returned items. Is there a way to not iterate through all the list twice (once for filtering and once for item instantiating), but do everything once? maybe something like checking the filter condition in the `getView` method and then decide if the item should be created or not?

2) After I filter the items, I override the original list with the filtered one. Does it mean I need to keep a copy of the list and always switch between the original and the copy after I'm changing the filter query (which can be changed on every key pressed)?

Comment: what adapter / data model are you using ?

Comment: It's a generic adapter I implemented that eventually extends BaseAdapter directly

Comment: But I actually got a different object just for the getView method to seperate the adapter and the gui elemtns.

Comment: why dont you use an Adapter that already implements Filterable ?

Comment: 1. it is what ArrayAdapter does. 2. yes you have to

Comment: @pskink I didn't know there were adapters that already implements it. I've only seen examples on how to do it manually. but like I said, I got a different object just for the getView implementation and my adapters is a wrapper for a another adapter and this view provider object.

Comment: so what Adapter do you wrap ?

Comment: a base adapter wraps : 1)another base adapter which implements an interface.  2) a view provider object.

Comment: so where do you have performance issues? maybe it is because you wrap another adapter?

Comment: It's not that it's slow.. I just want to know if the filter and getView can be done in a single iteration